# Cakephp 3.7 how to disable auth error messages

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to disable auth error messages in the application as there are already custom messages that are implemented within the application and auth error messages are duplicating error messages in some places.

Below is the Auth object details

> Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent Object (
>       [components] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => RequestHandler
>               [1] => Flash
>           )
>
> ```
> [implementedEvents] => Array
>     (
>         [Controller.initialize] => authCheck
>         [Controller.startup] => startup
>     )
>
> [_config] => Array
>     (
>         [authenticate] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => Form
>             )
>
>         [authorize] => 
>         [ajaxLogin] => 
>         [flash] => Array
>             (
>                 [element] => error
>                 [key] => flash
>                 [params] => Array
>                     (
>                         [class] => error
>                     )
>
>             )
>
>         [loginAction] => Array
>             (
>                 [controller] => Users
>                 [action] => login
>                 [plugin] => 
>             )
>
>         [loginRedirect] => 
>         [logoutRedirect] => 
>         [authError] => You are not authorized to access that location.
>         [unauthorizedRedirect] => 1
>         [storage] => Session
>         [checkAuthIn] => Controller.startup
>     )
> ```
>
> )

I want to disable [authError] => You are not authorized to access that location. this is randomly appearing on the site. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to disable authError in your controller’s `beforeFilter()` or component settings:

`$this->Auth->config('authError', false);`